# How do I make this equation more round?

Tags: geometry, circles, graphing-functions, spherical-coordinates

This is my equation: $e^{-0.5*{2^y} - 0.5 *{ 2^x}}$

My goal is to create a 3D semi-circle that starts off at a corner with a z value of 1, then as it goes to the opposing corners it decays to a z of zero. My equation as it stands now makes a semi box with a rounded edge.

I'm not the most eloquent person, so if this doesn't make sense, I can clarify.

*Edit* Going off of the great help from Théophile. Looking at the bottom picture of the figure, how do I increase the size of the innermost circle, without changing any of the decay properties?[Wolframalpha Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT5hm.png)

Comment: If you want a hemisphere, how about $z = \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$?

Comment: Consider also $e^{-(x/a)^2-(y/a)^2}$ for whatever value of $a$ is suitable.

Comment: Do you know of any way to shift this equation. So I modified your equation slightly to be: e^(-0.5*(-x/10)^2 - 0.5* (y/10)^2). I was wonder if there is a way to shift it equally in the x and y direction. In other words, move the hemisphere out by a given value, where the shifted portion for the origin is 1, then past the shifted point, it decays in the z direction just like how the equation works now.

Comment: It would be based on some sort of addition in the numerator

Comment: To shift it so that it is centred at $(h,k)$, try $e^{-((x-h)/a)^2-((y-k)/a)^2}$.

Comment: I guess shift wasn't the correct verbiage. Where could I put an addition variable to increase the size of the hemisphere about the origin? Check out the new edit and figure I placed in the original post.

Comment: Do you mean that you want it to flatter, then drop off more suddenly? (So it might be closer to a cylinder than a hemisphere?) If so, then try $$\exp\left(\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}\right)^w + \left(\frac{y^2}{a^2}\right)^w\right)$$
and experiment with $w$. ($w = 1$ produces the curve I gave above; higher values make it steeper.) Incidentally, the $0.5$ in your equation is redundant, since $-0.5\left(\frac x{10}\right)^2 = \left(\frac x{10\sqrt2}\right)^2$.

Comment: Théophile, you are God walking among mere mortals. I am going to try and play around with the formulas to try and get the correct version of it.

Comment: Ha! Thank you; I'm glad to help out. :) If you have more questions later, ask away.

Comment: So I am still having some issues with the equation @Théophile. I was wondering if there is any chatroom or something we could discuss the issue. But I have slightly changed my goal. I am trying to make effectively 2 independencies in the equation. The first is a cylinder with a height unchanging from 1. The x and y values are adjustable to increase the radius. Then, beyond the radius, the formula should decay exponentially from 1 to 0. What should be adjustable is decay "speed," i.e. if the decay is immediate from 1 to 0 or if it decays more gradually. I know this is convoluted but thank you!